# jQuery how to find an data element value

Tags: jquery, html, find, each, element

I have this html code:

```
<body>
....
<span data-code="code100">...</span>
....
<div data-code="code101">...</div>
<input type="test" ... data-code="code102">...</input>
...
<b data-code="code103">...</b>
etc...
</body>
```

Now I want to find all elements with [data-code] and get the data-code value (code100, code101, code 103, code104)

This don't work:

```
var arr = $("[data-code]");
    $.each(arr, function(key) {
        alert($(key).data('data-code'));
    });
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Check $.fn.data method doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work-

```
var arr = $("[data-code]");
 $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
  alert($(this).data('code'));
});
```

You can refer to data values like this. your data key is 'code'. 
read more about Jquery.data() [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Try this example with opened developer console.

```js
var arr = $("[data-code]");
$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
  console.log($(this).attr('data-code'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span data-code="code100"></span>
<div data-code="code101"></div>
<input type="test" data-code="code102" />
<b data-code="code103"></b>
```